# Calling foreign key object several times in Django without several DB requests

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

Let’s say that I have a class `Child` linked, through a FK, to another class `Parent`. Now let’s say I have a block of code doing something like this in a template

```
<td>{{ child.parent.name }}</td>
<td>{{ child.parent.age}}</td>
<td>{{ child.parent.address }}</td>
```

My first question is, will Django go to the database and read the `Parent` entity three times? My second question is: if yes, what is the best practice not to read it multiple times? I mean I know I can declare an object before this block and set it equal to `child.parent` but is there another way to do that?

Comment: Look into select_related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Django will hit DB only once, next call will use cached attribute and will not requred access to DB, you can check related [part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/#understand-cached-attributes) of documentation.

But you can impove this by using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method, in this case even first call will not hit DB, since `child.parent` will be precached.

Answer (score 3):

Use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

In your view, get the Child objects like this:

```
children = Child.objects.select_related('parent').all()
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement neverwalkaloner's answer, you can also alias `child.parent` in your template to avoid the lookup cost:

```
{% with parent=child.parent %}
<td>{{ parent.name }}</td>
<td>{{ parent.age}}</td>
<td>{{ parent.address }}</td>
{% endwith %}
```